# Print Simplified Chinese Character using Raw Printing

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, thermal-printer, epson, qz-tray

I am using Epson TM-T82 thermal receipt printer and QZ tray to print the receipt.
When I try to print the Chinese characters, odd characters produced.

Below is the configs setting and encoding,

var config = qz.configs.create(printer, {encoding: 'GB18030'});

I also tried print to FILE: printer and view with Visual Studio Code with GB18030 encoding, as per suggested by Tres on thread

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/qz-print/jp68IuW-LcA

So, I think I needs correct configuration for GB18030 for my printer model.

Any things else I can do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Three things need to occur:

1. You need a printer capable of printing Chinese (some require special firmware, if outside of China, expect export restrictions on this firmware)
2. You need to know which character encoding that printer supports.
3. You need to supply the commands to do so.

Code:

```
var config = qz.configs.create("Printer Name", {encoding: 'Big5'});  // *Epson T88 models with correct firmware.  Toggles Big5 with Hong Kong extensions.
                                            // {encoding: 'GBK'});   // Fuken POS90 ships with GB18030, but in testing, 'GBK' is required

var printData = [
   '\x1B' + '\x40',   // ESC @ - init command, necessary for proper byte interpretation
   '艾德蒙 AOC E2450SWH 23.6吋\n',
   ' LED液晶寬螢幕特價$ 19900',
   '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A',
   '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A' + '\x0A',
   '\x1B' + '\x69'          // cut paper
];

qz.print(config, printData);
```

Some programming manuals also specify:

```
var printData = [
    // ... 
    '\x1C' + '\x26' // Enter Hanzi (Japanese/Chinese/ Taiwanese/Korean Kanji Specifications) mode
    // ...
];
```

**Note:** When testing, the Traditional Chinese did NOT have an "International Character Set" command like other languages.  Hopefully this information helps.